# Something is going wrong with my EventWaithandle, it doesn't change to signaled?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, event-handling

So I'm working on a windows 8 application with some asynchronous methods.
In one particular place I need the aplication to wait for the async method to finish, but it doesn't seem it sends the EventHandle it's state.

Here are the methods that need to work together:

```
public class Film : Page

private User loggedinUser = new User();
private EventWaitHandle handle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
private dynamic parameters;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.parameters = e.Parameter;
    LoadFacebookData(parameters);
    handle.WaitOne();
    LoadUserMovies(loggedinUser.UserName);

}

private async void LoadFacebookData(dynamic parameter)
{
    //async code that gets info from facebook whichs determines what user is logged in
    handle.Set();
}

private void LoadUserMovies(string username)
{
    // irrelevant code
}
```

the moment the code hits the `handle.WaitOne()` bit, it stops working completely

Comment: Does the execution hits the `handle.Set();` line?

Comment: If you are using the `async` keyword, why doesn't you just `await LoadFacebookData(parameters);` rather than using the wait handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you are not supposed to use async and wait on something. The standard mistake is to wait on the task returned (deadlock). You did a variation on this: You created an event and waited on it (also deadlock).

Solution: Either embrace async-await or don't do async at all. Can't do both in a mixed style (generally).

If await is available to you, this is a good start:

```
await LoadFacebookData(parameters);
```

Get rid of the event.

Comment: How is this a deadlock? I can't imagine any execution-flow that would make the code given to us a deadlock. In my head (though I might be mistaken), the reason this does not work has to be in the ´// async code that gets from facebook´.

Comment: For references, this works just fine: http://monobin.com/1548/
There is no problem mixing async with non-async code (in general, to use async at all it's actually required, because the main-method can't be async, but this is generally hidden from you).

Comment: @Alxandr ASP.NET has a a synchronizationcontext that you cannot repro in that console app. The async method posts to it and the post internally waits till the `WaitOne` is completed. Deadlock. ASP.NET tries to make your code single-threaded and reentrancy-free (desirable!).

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure the sample is adequate anymore (you made a valid point), but `new SynchronizationContext().Send(o => new AsyncTest().Run(), null);` still works...

Comment: What "context" did you use? Here's a useful table: http://nitoprograms.blogspot.de/2009/10/synchronizationcontext-properties.html In the OPs code the not-shown async code comes back on the thread-pool and cannot enter the syncctx.

Comment: I used a generic SynchronizationContext. However, after testing some more I've concluded that you are indeed correct. In ASP.net this does indeed create a deadlock. The `Task.Wait()` approach does not work either. I take my hat of to you sir, you were entirely correct, and I'm proven wrong, and learnt something new yet again :)

Comment: @Alxandr: I have [a detailed explanation of this kind of deadlock on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the

```
await LoadFacebookData(parameters);
```

code line to get the execution continue on the same thread it was started once your async operation finishes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with the code you have posted. This leads me to believe that the problem is in the code you have commented away. The problem is probably that your code-execution never reaches the line

```
handle.Set();
```

This can be because of an exception, or your async code simply never completes. To "deal" with the possibility of an exception, you should probably use the builtin Wait-method of the Task-object, rather than your own EventWaitHandle.

You can remove the EventWaitHandle as a whole, and simply do:

```
LoadFacebookData(parameters).Wait();
```

This will propagate any exceptions that occur in the thread within.